# CodeSniffer case indentation issue

Tags: php, netbeans-7, phpcodesniffer

I'm using Netbeans 7.1.1 with codesniffer. Whenever I have a `case` statement I get indentation errors, e.g. for the following code:

```
    switch ((int) $itemData['column_count']) {
        case 4:
            return 'grid-4columns';
        case 6:
            return 'grid-6columns';
        default:
            return '';
    }
```

I get "Line indented incorrectly; expected 8 spaces, found 12" for every `case` line.  When I remove 4 spaces from those lines, e.g.

```
    switch ((int) $itemData['column_count']) {
    case 4:
        return 'grid-4columns';
    case 6:
        return 'grid-6columns';
    default:
        return '';
    }
```

I get errors "Line indented incorrectly; expected 12 spaces, found 8". Seems like codesniffer can't make up its mind, which is quite funny. The fun ends when my commits fail because of the codesniffer hook.

What is the problem with my `case` indentation?

UPDATE: I have only one indentation rule in my ruleset:

```
<rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent" />
```

Comment: Please show which concrete codesniffer rules are used that are causing those errors.

Comment: I think, the sniffer class is `Generic_Sniffs_WhiteSpace_ScopeIndentSniff`

Comment: When I try this on your first code block (assuming the SWITCH is indented correctly, or not indented at all in a test file) I get no errors reported from the sniff. I used the command: `phpcs temp.php --standard=Generic --sniffs=Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent`

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue using `<rule ref="PEAR.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent" />` and I fixed it just switching to `<rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent" />`

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to ignore indentation issues for specific tokens:

```
<!-- If you are using Generic -->
<rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent">
    <properties>
        <property name="ignoreIndentationTokens" type="array" value="T_COMMENT,T_DOC_COMMENT_OPEN_TAG,T_CASE" />
    </properties>
</rule>

<!-- If you are using PEAR -->
<rule ref="PEAR.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent">
    <properties>
        <property name="ignoreIndentationTokens" type="array" value="T_COMMENT,T_DOC_COMMENT_OPEN_TAG,T_CASE" />
    </properties>
</rule>
```

Notice the `T_CASE`. This prevents the sniffer from checking your `case:` rules.

[Here is a list of tokens](https://github.com/alienari/phpcs/blob/master/PHP_CodeSniffer/CodeSniffer/Tokens.php)